# CSS shadow under block element (NOT with box-shadow, with an image of shadow, the old way)

Tags: html, css, background, photoshop

My task is to put shadow on images without using the box-shadow CSS property. I have been given a PSD image, from which I have to cut the shadow and place it around the block element. I have alredy placed the right shadow. The shadow is actualy 5 transparent pixels repeating until the end of the element.

```
img:after {

    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    top: 10%;
    content: "";
    height: 90%;
background: url(pictures/shadow_right.png) repeat-y 0% 0%;
}
```

Any ideas how I can place a shadow under the block element, which will fit for all image sizes? I also need to put a corner shadow, which is also under the element, but a little bit to the right (I can probably do that on my own, after someone gives me the basic idea of putting a background image under block element). My task is to write a universal CSS code, that will put shadow under all images.

[Here's a picture](http://i43.tinypic.com/2rhusf5.png) of what the result should be.

Comment: It sounds like I'd approach it using 5 images. 1 for each of the corners (top-right, bot-right, bot-left) and 1 for each of the sides (left, bot). The corner images you draw at full-size, the 1-pixel high(side img) or wide(top img) side images you repeat or stretch depending on which is faster/less memory intensive/gives a better looking result. It would however, need extra html, which you could easily insert with a small snippet of javascript. I'm thinking along the lines of the 9-squares technique that used to be used for drawing boxes with rounded corners.

Comment: The shadow begins on about 10% from top (side shadow) and about the same % from left for the bottom shadow. I only need 1 corner (for bottom right). My problem is only 1 - I have no idea how to set a background image UNDER a block element. For the sides its clear - a simple css :after. Do you have any idea for the bottom?

Comment: I saw a mistake in my code, so I fixed it. ;)

Comment: @user3127242, what is the specific reason for not wanting to use `box-shadow`? I'm asking because other ways to handle this like `background-size` won't be possible in many cases where `box-shadow` isn't possible.

Comment: I am taking programming lessons and that's my task. That's why I have been given this image

Comment: @user3127242, got it, just use `background-size` I guess, although this will shrink the shadow on smaller images so they'll appear to be closer to the page. `box-shadow` would really be better unless this is for mobile or the image is doing something fancy.

Comment: It looks like you also need to look into [multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).

Comment: What do you mean? I have 6px shadow, that must be repeated until the end of the image. How do I place this shadow under the image?

Comment: @user3127242 you can just give the images some padding and use background images positioned at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks :). It look like it would work

Answer (score 0):

try this code it's work for me

```
img:after
{
content:"";
display:block;
background:url("pictures/shadow_right.png");
background-size:100% 100%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I have no problems with the side shadow. I am asking if you have any idea how to put a shadow under the image (just a basic idea). I don't need a fully working code, as I haven't given a shadow image too. Just a hint will be fine ;)

Comment: yes the code for put shadow under div or image which will fit for all div/image sizes